# Odd behavior adding to $PATH - ZSH

Tags: command-line, zsh

ZSH 5.8
Everywhere I've seen, the method I keep seeing for adding a directory to my ZSH $PATH has been adding to my .zshrc `export PATH=/what/i/add:$PATH` and while this did add what I wanted to my path, every time I loaded up ZSH, the same addition was made another time, as in, `echo $PATH` returns: `/what/i/add:/what/i/add:/rest/of/path`, getting longer every time my .zshrc runs. How do I get around this? I have already managed to reset my $PATH to what it was before I made any changes, but I still want to add a directory to my $PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See
*A User’s Guide to the Z-Shell*
Peter Stephenson
2003/03/23
paragraph 2.5.11:

> The incantation ‘typeset -U
> path’, where the -U stands for unique, tells the shell that it should not add anything to
> $path if it’s there already. To be precise, it keeps only the left-most occurrence, so if you
> added something at the end it will disappear and if you added something at the beginning,
> the old one will disappear. Thus the following works nicely in .zshenv:
> typeset -U path
> path=(~/bin ~/progs/bin $path)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Very much appreciated!